# How to take the data between two strings in a file Linux

Tags: python-3.x, shell, awk, csh

I want to get the lines between `forwarders {`  and  `};` those are IP address, below is the sample file which mimics my data..

```
// Red Hat BIND Configuration Tool
//
// THIS IS THE SLAVE DDNS SERVER -
//

// Currently running in chroot environment
// Prefix all file names below with /var/named/chroot
options {
        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        recursion yes;
        check-names master ignore;
        check-names slave ignore;
        check-names respocope ignore;
        max-journal-size 2M;
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-update {
                key copdcop1.example.com.;
                key copdcop2.example.com.;
                key copdcop3.example.com.;
                key copdcop4.example.com.;
        };

        forward only;
        forwarders {
      192.168.174.131;     // cop-no1
      192.155.98.74;        // cop-jn1
      192.168.2.40;       // cop-sad1
      192.168.2.56;       // cop-s1
      192.43.4.70;        // cop-che1
      192.20.28.8;      // copdcop1
        };
```

### Desired Result:

```
      192.168.174.131;     // cop-no1
      192.155.98.74;        // cop-jn1
      192.168.2.40;       // cop-sad1
      192.168.2.56;       // cop-s1
      192.43.4.70;        // cop-che1
      192.20.28.8;      // copdcop1
```

I'm okay with any solution either shell or python or awk.

I tried with sed but no luck..

```
sed -n '"/forwarders {"/,/"};"' dns.txt
```

However, below awk code works ..

```
awk '/forwarders {/{flag=1;next}/};/{flag=0}flag' dns.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP asked to have output into single line so adding following solution now.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} /}/{found=""} /forwarders {/{found=1} found && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){gsub(/ +/," ");val=(val?val OFS:"")$0}END{print val}'  Input_file
```

OR non-one liner form of solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
/}/{
  found=""
}
/forwarders {/{
  found=1
}
found && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
  gsub(/ +/," ")
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  print val
}'  Input_file
```

OR as mentioned before too, to print anything inside forwarder block try:

```
awk '/}/{found=""} /forwarders {/{found=1;next} found{gsub(/ +/," ");val=(val?val OFS:"")$0} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(considering that you only need to print IP addresses inside the tag).

```
awk '/}/{found=""} /forwarders {/{found=1} found && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)'  Input_file
```

In case forwarders tag you want to anything then try following.

```
awk '/}/{found=""} /forwarders {/{found=1;next} found'  Input_file
```

Comment: @-Ravinder, i know i need to accept one of the answers which suits best but i was in discussion with previous answer hence awaited this for now.. i'll surely make it accepted :-)

Comment: can we make teh output  like `192.168.174.131;     // cop-no1,  192.155.98.74;        // cop-jn1` as one liner?

Comment: @-Ravinder this works, can this as a one line? work perfect though.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n '/forwarders {/,/};/{//!p}' file
```

Given your sample its output:

```
      192.168.174.131;     // cop-no1
      192.155.98.74;        // cop-jn1
      192.168.2.40;       // cop-sad1
      192.168.2.56;       // cop-s1
      192.43.4.70;        // cop-che1
      1192.20.28.8;      // copdcop1
```

Comment: the `!p` runs the last command from my shell history :-), works well in bash

Comment: @kulfi how and why?

Comment: @-oguz, because shell takes `!p` as a command history to repeat the last ran command specially `csh`.

Comment: Ooh I didn't know that, thanks. It sounds weird though

Comment: In bash shell it works fine. thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @kulfi consider adding [tag:csh]  tag to your question if you want a solution for csh.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends in how much the file can change.

But this would work for your example:

```
 awk '/forwarders {/{flag=1;next}/};/{flag=0}flag' /path/to/file
```

For your example:

```
  192.168.174.131;     // cop-no1
  192.155.98.74;        // cop-jn1
  192.168.2.40;       // cop-sad1
  192.168.2.56;       // cop-s1
  192.43.4.70;        // cop-che1
  192.20.28.8;      // copdcop1
```

Comment: @-myradio.. i catch the same and it works..sorry i dont have much point to upvote

Comment: My +1 for the solution.